# a good form generator (without external dependencies)?`

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

I want to know if there exist a form generator that is capable of generating forms, mark validator(s) for element and whole form (or some like that) and been able to generate a json object and be filled with a json object.

If possible without any external large dependencies (like crafted by hand).

For clarification: the form should be made in client side javascript from an json object if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with using PHP, then I would highly recommend [php-form-builder-class](http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/). I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "external dependencies", but pfbc is pretty lightweight.

Comment: I was thinking of building it on the client side with javascript from an json object that come from the server.

Answer (score 1):

I had this very same question, and after some research, I ended up writing [outperform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/outperform) myself.  It's a small javascript form generator library that I recently wrote to support my own projects because I got fed up by the fact that all the form generators that I looked at either had a ton of dependencies, or were distinctly larger than my single page web-application.

I mean, let's face it: if my SPA is like 20KB unminified but gzipped, then I expect library routines which do something simple as generating a form to be significantly smaller.  Its main features would be:

- Zero dependencies.
- Less filling (unminified but gzipped: <2KB).
- Native HTML5/browser validation support for all HTML5+ input types.
- Custom validation seemlessly integrated.
- Supports all web frameworks out there (including Bootstrap).
- Autorefills half-filled forms when reloading a page in all browsers.
- JSON set/get for all form values.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered Outperform described by BuGless and it looks great, perfect for simple forms and NO DEPENDENCIES.  Thank you !
Now, I could use some examples of how it is being used in some real world use cases, if possible, as your documentation is a little bit sparse for a newbie like me.
Is there any chance if you read this that you can post some links to documentation or examples ?
Thanks very much.